# What's the underlying transport layer protocol when etcd node sends out a heartbeat

Tags: etcd

Should it be `UDP` or `TCP`? If it's the latter one, wouldn't it cost too much overhead on network via three-time shaking and four-time waving?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo netstat -nap | grep etcd
[sudo] password for emma: 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21731/etcd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21731/etcd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21731/etcd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2380          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21731/etcd
```